# CSS Grid with input fields: alignment question

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am using CSS Grid (12 columns) with inputs fields. Due to the way I am creating the form (the form design is in JSON and created on the fly) the input fields are not the direct children of the grid but are wrapped in a div. If I do a *grid-column: span* of the div I also want the input field to span the columns - but not over the *grid-gap*. I have tried multiple ways of doing this and the best seems to be *width: 100%* on the input BUT this ignores the grid gap. Any idea as to how I can get the input field to be the same width as the div?

Sorry if I explained it badly - here is a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

here the code:

```css
   .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 20px;
        background-color: black;
      }

      .fill-width {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .width-4 {
        grid-column: span 4;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <input id="field1" class="width-4" placeholder="field1 (4)" />
      <input id="field2" class="width-4" placeholder="field2 (4)" />
      <input id="field3" class="width-4" placeholder="field3 (4)" />

      <div class="width-4">
        <input id="field5" placeholder="field5 (4)" />
      </div>
      <input id="field6" class="width-4" placeholder="field6 (4)" />
      <input id="field7" class="width-4" placeholder="field7 (4)" />

      <div class="width-4">
        <input id="field1" class="fill-width" placeholder="field1 (4)" />
      </div>
      <div class="width-4">
        <input id="field2" class="fill-width" placeholder="field2 (4)" />
      </div>
      <div class="width-4">
        <input id="field3" class="fill-width" placeholder="field3 (4)" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

and the codepen example:
https://codepen.io/ursus_the_bear/pen/mdRQNXM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong that you are doing, but let me explain why this happens and the solution.

input elements have some css which the browser adds. like border, max-width and stuff. you need to get rid of those, for your inputs to follow your stylesheet strictly.

add this to the CSS for this to work like a charm:

```
* { /* all element selector */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* border, within the width of the element */
}
input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}
```

if `* {box-sizing: border-box; }` looks new to you, you can remove the margin and border from input to get the perfect result.

```
 input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much - I know understand what I was doing wrong 

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. To ensure that the inputs do not overflow into the grid-gap, you could look into the `box-sizing` property. But since another answer has already demonstrated that, I'll provide an alternative approach.

You could try using flexbox. I made the divs in the `container` class flex parents, and then gave the inputs in those divs a `flex-grow` of 1. This ensures that the flex child takes up all the extra space in the flex parent. To make sure that the inputs do not overflow, I gave them a `max-width` of 100%. I also removed the `width` declaration for the `fill-width` class:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

.width-4 {
  grid-column: span 4;
}


/* New styles */

.container div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.container div input {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="field1" class="width-4" placeholder="field1 (4)" />
  <input id="field2" class="width-4" placeholder="field2 (4)" />
  <input id="field3" class="width-4" placeholder="field3 (4)" />

  <div class="width-4">
    <input id="field5" placeholder="field5 (4)" />
  </div>
  <input id="field6" class="width-4" placeholder="field6 (4)" />
  <input id="field7" class="width-4" placeholder="field7 (4)" />

  <div class="width-4">
    <input id="field1" class="fill-width" placeholder="field1 (4)" />
  </div>
  <div class="width-4">
    <input id="field2" class="fill-width" placeholder="field2 (4)" />
  </div>
  <div class="width-4">
    <input id="field3" class="fill-width" placeholder="field3 (4)" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you answer neither explains why the former piece of code did not work. nor it explains why your piece of code works. Stick to Explanations first, and then come to a solution. This will add value to your answer.

Comment: @SudiptoRoy I was editing my answer after posting the initial version. An approach that you followed for your answer as well, Smarty Pants

Comment: you are stalking... :D ... just kidding...!!! All the best.

Comment: Hahaha. Thanks! @SudiptoRoy. Just edited my answer. Have a look! I was gonna use the border-box property too but you answered it first so I up-voted it and provided an alternative :)

Comment: thank you for your answer - I went with the option below as it did not use display: flex